# Kafka Producer error on java 1.6

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I am trying to run kafka producer on java 1.6 , i am using version 0.8.1.1. It is running but when it try to send the message it give

```
Exception in thread "Main" kafka.common.FailedToSendMessageException: Failed to send messages after 3 tries.
        at kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler.handle(DefaultEventHandler.scala:90)
        at kafka.producer.Producer.send(Producer.scala:76)
        at kafka.javaapi.producer.Producer.send(Producer.scala:33)
```

Same code if i run it on java 1.8 it works and i am able to produce message.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was network issue , after fixing the logging i was able to read the correct error , network timeout and fixed it .